# find element contains text when nested <img> tag

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I need to find the `a`(the nearest) element which contains word 'Integrations'

```
const htmlStr = `
<ul class="yy">
   <li>
      <a href="/organisations/xx/team">
      <img src="xx.png" alt="Team">
      Team
      </a> 
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="/organisations/xx/connections">
      <img src="xx.png" alt="Integrations">
      Integrations
      </a> 
   </li>
</ul>
`
```

Following are my codes in `Devtool`

```
const htmlObj = document.createElement('div')
htmlObj.innerHTML = htmlStr
const elements = document.evaluate('.//*[contains(text(), "Integrations")]', htmlObj, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null)
console.log(elements.snapshotItem(0))
```

I cannot find anything as `elements.snapshotItem(0) is null`

But when I remove `<img>` tag, then I can find the `<a>`. Say the codes works for following string.

```
const htmlStr = `
<ul class="yy">
   <li>
      <a href="/organisations/xx/team">
      Team
      </a> 
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="/organisations/xx/connections">
      Integrations
      </a> 
   </li>
</ul>
`
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a html element *(img)*, the code will ignore the **a tag** because it doesn't have the **Integrations** string as immediate child. (the code works if the string **Integrations** stay **above** the **img** tag)

See this code:

```
const htmlObj = document.createElement('div')
htmlObj.innerHTML = htmlStr
const elements = document.evaluate('.//a[contains(., "Integrations")]', htmlObj, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null)
console.log(elements.snapshotItem(0))
```

As you can see, I did change **'.//*[contains(*text()*, "Integrations")]'** to **'.//a[contains(*.*, "Integrations")]'**

When you use **text()**, means that you're looking for the **immediate child** text node equals to 'Integrations`.

but, if you're using **.**, means that you're looking for the string **Integration** at **any position** and this is why the code above works even if the **Integration** string is below the **img *(or any)*** html tag.

Answer (score 0):

please Change this your image tag not end so this issue created ..!!

```
<ul class="yy">
       <li>
          <a href="/organisations/xx/team">
          <img src="xx.png" alt="Team"/>
          Team
          </a> 
       </li>
       <li>
          <a href="/organisations/xx/connections">
          <img src="xx.png" alt="Integrations"/>
          Integrations
          </a> 
       </li>
    </ul>
    `
```